# Animate a view from the side in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

Say I have this view:

```
struct CircleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
    }
}
```

In another view, I have something like this:

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        ZStack {
            //some other views
                
            if someState == .showCircle {
                CircleView()
            }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
```

When `someState` becomes `.showCircle`, I want to have the CircleView animate in from the right side of the screen into a position where the left hemisphere is visible, so it's halfway on the screen, and dim the rest of the content in the ZStack. What's the best way to set up this kind of animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `.transition()` modifier on the circle, and the `.blur()` modifier on the other views that are *not* the circle, combined with `.animation()`.

Also, on the views that are "not circle", you need to add another modifier: `.allowsHitTesting()`, to avoid having the user interacting with the views that are blurred.

Remember that, when you trigger `someState`, you **must** use the `.withAnimation()` closure, otherwise the circle will not slide in.

Here's how the code looks like (I added some things on the `ZStack` just to provide an example). I also made the `someState` variable a boolean for convenience in the example, but in your case you can just check for the enum.

**CircleView**

```
struct CircleView: View {
    @Binding var someState: Bool
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .overlay(Text("All is blur"))
            .onTapGesture {
                someState.toggle()
            }
        
        // These modifiers are necessary to animate the circle
            .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
            .animation(.easeInOut, value: someState)
    }
}
```

**Another view**

```
    @State private var someState = false
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    Button {
                        
                        // Without this closure, the circle does not slide in
                        withAnimation {
                            someState.toggle()
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text("Show circle")
                    }
                    .padding()
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Text("Bottom")
                        .padding()
                }
                
                // This modifier blurs the view that is not the circle
                .blur(radius: someState ? 5 : 0)
                
                // This modifier animates the blur effect
                .animation(.easeInOut, value: someState)
                
                // This is necessary to block the view from accepting user taps
                // when the circle is showing
                .allowsHitTesting(!someState)
                
                if someState {
                    CircleView(someState: $someState)

                        // Stop the circle half-way
                        .offset(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, y: 0)
                }
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is great, thank you. The circle animates in from the right. However, it animates to the center of the screen. How can I control the positioning such that it ends up halfway on the screen, with only the left hemisphere being visible?

Comment: @soleil: add an `.offset()` modifier to the `CircleView()`. I have updated the answer, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5.6** You can use offset property along with animation. Here is a example code

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isAnimating = false
    var viewWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("Select an item")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .font(.system(size: 22))
                .offset(x: isAnimating ? 0 : viewWidth)
                .opacity(isAnimating ? 1 : 0)
                .animation(.easeOut(duration: 1), value: isAnimating)
        }.onAppear {
            isAnimating = true
        }
    }
}
```

View will at right End
[image]
Final position after animation
[image]